# Returning JSON from an API/website in a firebase project

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase-hosting

I am working on a little website on Firebase, which is meant to be used as an API, returning JSON data, for some other customer sites.

Since this is the first time I build something like this I hit a few issues on the way.

This site is the second website on a Firebase project. The first site is a more standard website and already works as intended.

Here is my *index.js* file:

```
import {initializeApp} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js'
import {getDatabase,ref,onValue} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ".....",
    authDomain: ".....",
    databaseURL: ".....",
    projectId: ".....",
    storageBucket: ".....",
    messagingSenderId: ".....",
    appId: ".....",
    measurementId: "....."
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


function showIfExist(element,name) {
  if (typeof element != 'undefined') console.log(name+':'+element)
}


const db = getDatabase();
const dbRef = ref(db, 'TopCollection/NiceArea');
onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data)

  data.map((item) => {
    showIfExist(item.mainField,'mainField')
    showIfExist(item.secondField,'secondField')
    showIfExist(item.comment,'comment')
    showIfExist(item.extraComment,'extraComment')
    showIfExist(item.price,'price')
  })
});
```

In case this may be useful here is the *index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>API</title>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>API-PAGE</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the *hosting record* inside the *firebase.json* file for this site:

```
{
  "target": "myapi",
  "public": "myapi/public",
  "headers": [{
    "source": "**",
    "headers": [{
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value": "*"
    }, {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "value": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Finally this is the question I have, for which I need some help:

Although the code above is functionnally working and shows in the Web Developer Tools Console of my browser, what I expect.
I want the result to be JSON data to appear in the browser.

How can I make that happen?